# Parse a nested data structure(object) and map it to another data structure object c#

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, data-structures, nested

I have a complex object in play with many nested levels, with each level in turn can have nests.

To put it in a diagram,

[image]

There is a data structure "condition" under which there can be conditional or logical operators.

Each logical operator can have any no of logical or condition operators inside.

My problem here is, I have to traverse through this nested condition object and
modify this nested condition object which is internal to the system and transform it into another condition DS of similar form which we are exposing outside in the form of WS.

The other DS is of similar form with a condition object with conditional and logical operators. I have to do a lot of type casting and string conversion for the mapping to the new object. But thats fine.

The only problem here is I am finding it difficult to loop through the levels and associate each leaf node to its parent. I tried recursion, but I lose the context . For ex, if i traverse through the OR condition, i lose track of AND, which is its parent, which in turn has 2 equals conditions.

I need  a way to traverse this tree like structure and store it in a object and then transform the object into another similar form.

This is what i tried so far.

```
if (constraint.Condition != null)
                    {
                        EvaluateCondition(constraint.Condition);
                        OxpdConditions[] _nestedConditionsMapToArray = new OxpdConditions[_nestedConditionsMap.Count];
                        _nestedConditionsMapToArray = _nestedConditionsMap.ToArray();

                        if (_nestedConditionsMapToArray[0].Condition == "AND")
                        {

                            int conditionDepth = _nestedConditionsMapToArray[0].NestedConditionCount;
                            And and = new And();

                            for (int i = 0; i < conditionDepth; i++)
                            {
                                switch (_nestedConditionsMapToArray[i + 1].Condition)
                                {
                                    case "EQUAL":
                                        Equals andEqual = new Equals();
                                        andEqual.optionName = constraint.Condition.NestedConditions[i].PropertyName;
                                        andEqual.optionValue = constraint.Condition.NestedConditions[i].PropertyValue.ToString();
                                        break;
                                    case "OR":
                                        Or andOr = new Or();

                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }




                     private void EvaluateCondition(ICondition condition)
        {
            if (condition != null)
            {
                if (condition.NestedConditions != null)
                {
                    OxpdConditions rootItem = new OxpdConditions();
                    rootItem.Condition = condition.ConditionType.ToString();
                    rootItem.NestedConditionCount = condition.NestedConditions.Count;
                    _nestedConditionsMap.Add(rootItem);

                    foreach (var con in condition.NestedConditions)
                    {
                        if (con.ConditionType == ConditionType.EQUAL)
                        {
                            OxpdConditions nestedItem = new OxpdConditions();
                            nestedItem.Condition = con.ConditionType.ToString();
                            nestedItem.NestedConditionCount = 0;
                            _nestedConditionsMap.Add(nestedItem);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //_nestedConditionsMap.Add(con.ConditionType.ToString(), condition.NestedConditions.Count);
                            EvaluateCondition(con);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    OxpdConditions nonNestedItem = new OxpdConditions();
                    nonNestedItem.Condition = condition.ConditionType.ToString();
                    nonNestedItem.NestedConditionCount = 0;
                    _nestedConditionsMap.Add(nonNestedItem);
                }

            }
        }

public class OxpdConditions
        {
            public string Condition { get; set; }
            public int NestedConditionCount { get; set; }
        }

private Dictionary<string, int> _nestedConditionsMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

I am passing the condition object to the EvaluateCondition() method which in turns loops through the whole tree and adds the condition and the depth in a dictionary object. The dictionary object would look like,

{And,3},{or,2},(eq,0},{eq,0},(eq,0},{eq,0}

I am trying to extract data from this dictionary object and trying to map to another object. This is where I am stuck.

One thing to note is, the nesting levels are dynamic and vary for each condition. Under the OR condition there can another OR condition too.

Is there any dynamic way I can handle such kind of problem in C#. I have tried using LINQ but frankly I cant get any breakthrough.

Any pointers would be very useful. Thanks

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that include an object as close as possible to the one you are talking about.

Comment: Have each node hold a pointer to its parent and you'll be able to walk up and down the tree?

Comment: How to use pointers in c#?

Comment: @ZoharPeled This is the actual use case in hand. There are a set of constraints and for each constraint there are conditions.

Comment: Well, without you sharing your code, we can only estimate how it might be written based on your description. We might come up with a wrong estimate and this means you might get answers you can't use. To spare everyone the time waist, I suggest you show us at least how your current code looks like.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Please make sure it is a [mcve] so that we can copy, paste, and compile.

Comment: Added code too.

Comment: Pointer? Reference then...

Comment: Please someone help.